# Batch File that delete FOLDERS older than 7 days based on FOLDER name date

Tags: batch-file

Im Marvin and I'd like to write a batch file (that works with windows command prompt) which would delete all folders which are older than 7 days in a specific folder, but based on the date written in the file name and not the modification date of the files.

Here are how the files are named in the folder, they all follow this specific template : CYYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sorry for the question. I dont have much knowledge on creating batch file. I try to copy some of the solution on other thread related on my concern but their issue is file deletion with extension name. On my concern is folder deletion with a file name template which I already mentioned above.

This is my sample code based on Folder Name Format and Path/Location of the folders:
Folder Name Format: CYYYYMMDDHHMMSS (e.g. C20200527180716, C20200528123944)
Folder Path: F:/v9Backup

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=F:\v9backup"

REM set the number of days to substract
SET DAYS=7

REM Call function to check if the date is valid.
CALL :validdate "%days%" subdate
echo Older than: %subdate%
pushd "%folder%"

REM Get a list of the files
REM file pattern is: CYYYYMMDDHHMMSS
set "search=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=_" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b C* 2^>nul ^|findstr /I /R /C:"^C%search%"') DO (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "fdate=%%H"
set "fdate=!fdate:~0,8!"
IF !fdate! lss %subdate% del "%%G_%%H_%%I"
endlocal
)
popd
pause

endlocal
GOTO :EOF

:validdate
setlocal
set "day=%~1"
set rand=%random%
md "%temp%\dummy%rand%\empty%rand%"

REM Get todays date
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do 
set "dt=%%a"

REM set year month and day into its own variables.
set /a y=%dt:~0,4%
set /a m=1%dt:~4,2%
set /a d=1%dt:~6,2%

:loop
if "%day%"=="0" (
rd /s /q "%temp%\dummy%rand%"
endlocal &set "%~2=%y%%m:~-2%%d:~-2%"
GOTO :EOF
)
set /a d-=1

if %d% lss 101 (
set d=131
set /a m-=1

if %m% lss 101 (
    set m=112
    set /a y-=1
)
)

xcopy /d:%m:~-2%-%d:~-2%-%y% /t "%temp%\dummy%rand%\empty%rand%" 
"%temp%\dummy%rand%" >nul 2>&1 && (set /a day-=1 & goto loop) || goto loop

GOTO :EOF
```

However, it is not running properly. Could you please help me on these.

Answer (score 0):

Marvin - give this a try. I'm a novice as well, but believe this modified script will work for your needs. I've modified it to your specifications and have removed the pause which requires a keypress for the script to complete.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=F:\v9backup"

REM set the number of days to substract
SET DAYS=7

REM Call function to check if the date is valid.
CALL :validdate "%days%" subdate
echo Older than: %subdate%
pushd "%folder%"

REM Get a list of the files
REM file pattern is: CYYYYMMDDHHMMSS
set "search=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=C" %%G IN ('dir /a:d /b * 2^>nul ^|findstr /I /R /C:"^C%search%"') DO (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "fdate=%%G"
    set "fdate=!fdate:~0,8!"
    IF !fdate! lss %subdate% del /f /s /q "C%%G" 1>nul
    IF !fdate! lss %subdate% rmdir /s /q "C%%G"
    endlocal
)
popd

endlocal
GOTO :EOF

:validdate
setlocal
set "day=%~1"
set rand=%random%
md "%temp%\dummy%rand%\empty%rand%"

REM Get todays date
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

REM set year month and day into its own variables.
set /a y=%dt:~0,4%
set /a m=1%dt:~4,2%
set /a d=1%dt:~6,2%

:loop
if "%day%"=="0" (
    rd /s /q "%temp%\dummy%rand%"
    endlocal &set "%~2=%y%%m:~-2%%d:~-2%"
    GOTO :EOF
)
set /a d-=1

if %d% lss 101 (
    set d=131
    set /a m-=1

    if %m% lss 101 (
        set m=112
        set /a y-=1
    )
)

xcopy /d:%m:~-2%-%d:~-2%-%y% /t "%temp%\dummy%rand%\empty%rand%" "%temp%\dummy%rand%" >nul 2>&1 && (set /a day-=1 & goto loop) || goto loop

GOTO :EOF
```